Vitest Crashes on Run with Error require of ES Module
In a vite project of mine that runs without any errors, I wanted to integrate some tests with vitest.
When running the following command npm run test and I have a test file open for a react component, I get the following error:
 FAIL  src/components/shared/SomeComponent.test.jsx [ src/components/shared/SomeComponent.test.jsx ]
Error: require() of ES Module C:\...\ui\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\...\ui\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
 ❯ Object.<anonymous> node_modules/react-pdf/dist/cjs/index.js:30:28

The error is still there even if I go to vite.config.js
and add the following snippet:
plugins: [
  react(),
  eslintPlugin(),
  svgr(),
  commonjs({
    filter(id) {
      // Include `react-pdf` and `pdfjs-dist` for transformation
      if (
        id.includes('node_modules/react-pdf') ||
        id.includes('node_modules/pdfjs-dist')
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
  }),
]

Why does this error even show up? My application runs with 0 problems.
